# Problem on Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I = [a,b]$,  $f: I → R$ be continuous function on $I$ such  that for each $x$ in $I$ there exists y in $I$ such that, 
$|f(y)| ≤ (1/2)|f(x)|$

Then prove that there exists $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c) = 0$

How to start up? 
I know Intermediate value theorem but how can I use it?

Comment: But this just an example. How do I prove the result.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is not really of any use here, I think... Does the word "compact" mean anything to you in the context of real analysis?

Comment: Umm I think no. I get stuck. I know continuous functions maps compact set to a compact set. But what this result do here?

Comment: What does "compact" mean?

Answer (score 2):

As $I$ is compact, $f$ attains its minimum and maximum there (extreme value theorem). Therefore there exists $c \in I$ be such that $\lvert f(c) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x) \rvert$ for all $x \in I$. By hypothesis, there exists $y \in I$ such that $\lvert f(y) \rvert \leq \lvert f(c) \lvert/2 $. As we then have $$ 2\lvert f(y) \rvert \leq \lvert f(c) \lvert \leq \lvert f(y) \rvert,$$

the only possibility is $\lvert f(y) \rvert = 0$, i.e. $f(y) = 0$.

Comment: How $|f(c)| ≤ |f(y)|$ in inequality? and how the last line is concluded?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi $|f(c)| ≤ |f(y)|$ comes from assuming that $c$ is a minimum for $|f(x)|$. The last line is concluded because if we remove the middle part of the three-part inequality, we're left with $2\lvert f(y) \rvert \leq \lvert f(y) \rvert$. Remembering that absolute values are never negative, we are forced to conclude that $|f(y)| = 0$.

Comment: I know comments of thanks are not allowed. But thank u so much. Get it.

Comment: @Alex. Very nice!!

Answer (score 1):

If you proved it using the *intermediate value theorem* you would need a positive and negative value. This is not at all required with your requisites. A way to prove it is shown below.

First off all, note that $f\left(\left[a, b\right]\right)$ is an interval because of continuity. If you create a sequence that converges in this set, its limit will also be a part of this set.

You can create a sequence that converges to zero by picking $x_1$ at random and then letting every subsequent $x$ be such that

$$|f\left(x_{n+1}\right)|\le \left(\frac 12\right)|f\left(x_{n}\right)|\,.$$

This converges to zero, so $0 \in f\left(\left[a, b\right]\right)$.

Comment: if I considered a convergent sequence in $f([a,b])$ then its limit also a part of this set because $f([a,b])$ is closed set(since continuous function maps bounded closed interval to bounded closed interval) I think that's the reason the limit of convergent sequence in $f([a,b])$ belongs to $f([a,b])$

Comment: How you concluded this sequence converges to 0 ?

Comment: pick $epsilon>0$, then you choose n such that $1/2^n<epsilon/|f\left(x_{0}\right)|$.